# How can I know it's the end of com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I know it's the end of `com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot`?
(environment: Android studio 3.1.2)

The `nextFirestore()` method is to query 20 posts every time.
`showPosts()` method will show the query posts one by one.
At the 20th post, `showPosts()` will give user a dialogue
"continue or not"
If user answer yes, then call `nextFirestore()` method again.

Everything went well until at the end of posts.
the app will crash, it said:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.google.appName, PID: 27564
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
> at com.google.appName.Post$2.onEvent(Post.java:208)
> at com.google.appName.Post$2.onEvent(Post.java:188)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzg.onEvent(Unknown Source:1789)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzh.zza(SourceFile:28)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzi.run(Unknown Source:6)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

```
public void nextFirestore(DocumentSnapshot lastVisible)
    {
CollectionReference questionRef = db.collection("posts");
        mQuery = questionRef.startAfter(lastVisible)
                .limit(20);

        mRegistration = mQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e)
            {
                if (e != null)
                {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }
                List<Posts> realtimeList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DocumentSnapshot doc : value)
                {
                    Posts post = doc.toObject(Posts.class);
                    assert post != null;
                    post.postId = doc.getId();
                    realtimeList.add(question);
                }

                DocumentSnapshot lastVisible = value.getDocuments().get(value.size() -1);
                Log.d(TAG, "next last visible: " + lastVisible);
                showPosts(realtimeList,lastVisible);
        


            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you should be checking the size of the List returned by `value.getDocuments()` before you start indexing into it.  If it's zero, stop.